# Vast difference in crypto performance between standalone and debugger environment (react-native)

Tags: javascript, react-native, performance

I am developing a react-native application and run into a performance issue when using the crypto-browserify package. But only when the app is running standalone.

For example, when running with the react-native-debugger, performance is adequate. A RSA decryption, using a 4096 bit key, takes approx 350msec on the Android simulator. Using the same simulator but disabling debugging, the same decryption takes 15sec. This is 45x increase in processing time. Needless to say that the app is very very very slow...

I also noticed that window.crypto.subtle is undefined when running without the debugger. OTOH, crypto-browserify does not appear to use it.

Clearly, the environment is different. But what is the difference? Or, more importantly, where to start diagnosing this?

I am clueless at the moment and open to any suggestion.